# Problems to send data with spanish chars from android app but not from postman to a restful web service

Tags: android, postman

I have a web service RESTful that it saves to a data base. I pass data with JSON. 
If i pass a JSON from POSTMAN, all is ok. If i pass the data (JSON) from an android app, the server can not save to the data base IF THERE ARE SPANISH chars like "ó, ñ, etc.".

Why from postman yes and from android app not?.

I try adding ISO-8859-1 but it doesn't work. Where is the error? Sql server?, android app?, IIS?. If the data doesn't contain spanish chars, all is fine, with spanish chars, it doesn't work.

The code in the android app is like:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httpPost;

httpPost = new HttpPost("http://"...

httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json" );

httpPost.setHeader("charset", "ISO-8859-1");

JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();

try
{
    jSONObject.put("Mensaje", params[0].mensaje);
    jSONObject.put("IdUsuarioOrigen", params[0].idUsuarioOrigen);
    jSONObject.put("IdUsuarioDestino", params[0].idUsuarioDestino);

    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jSONObject.toString());

    stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");
    stringEntity.setContentEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    strHttpResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

EDIT::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

I'm debugging for some days. The point is this:

The code in android app is:

...
    httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json" );
    httpPost.setHeader("charset", "ISO-8859-9");

```
JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();

        try
        {
            jSONObject.put("Mensaje", params[0].mensaje);
            jSONObject.put("IdUsuarioOrigen", params[0].idUsuarioOrigen);
            jSONObject.put("IdUsuarioDestino", 
params[0].idUsuarioDestino);

            StringEntity stringEntity = new 
StringEntity(jSONObject.toString());

            stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");
            stringEntity.setContentEncoding("ISO-8859-9");
            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            strHttpResponse = 
EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

And if i debug httpPost before "httpClient.execute(httpPost);" the httpPost is ok, has the data inside (ó, ñ etc.) but when it arrives to the c# back-end, "mensaje" is null:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostMensaje(Mensajeria mensaje)
{
        if (mensaje == null)
            return 
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "El mensaje no 
puede llegar al servidor");
```

But if httpPost in android app doesn't have any spanish characters, all is well and in the back-end "Mensajeria mensaje" "mensaje" is not null. 
Why is null only for to carry spanish characters?.

With postman, all is well, with or without spanish chars.

I must yo say, my last attempt was to add web.config in web services .net:

```
  <globalization
      fileEncoding="ISO-8859-9" 
      requestEncoding="ISO-8859-9" 
     responseEncoding="ISO-8859-9"


  />
```

But the json when it reaches to the web service, "mensaje" is null (but it came out well of the android code). If JSON came out with "ó, ñ etc. "mensaje" in .net is null, otherwise, everything is perfect.

```
  public HttpResponseMessage PostMensaje(Mensajeria mensaje)
    {
```

Comment: The problem is that if there is spanish chars, the JSON when it arrives to the web service is null. If there aren't spanish chars (ó, ñ etc.) all is fine.

Comment: You're setting the content encoding, but the default encoding for a string in android is utf8.  I think you need to convert first.Just setting the entity encoding only sets the type, it doesn't actually convert.

Comment: I just edit my question with last discovery.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=utf-8" );
```

and

```
strHttpResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: The header would be "8859-1" for latin char set. And the strHttpResponse is only the response of the server, it is not important here. The problem is that the JSON data is well in the android code but it is null when it arrives to the c# code (web services). Null if the json contains a latin character, if not, all is good.

Comment: I think your problem is the communication format, both the mobile app and the backend should handle the same format either "charset = utf-8" or "charset = ISO-8859-1"